# Is there a way to convert an RDL filetype to a SHP filetype

Tags: shapefile, microstation

I Have an open records file from a county that provided an RDL file extension which we can view in MS 8 Viewer but is there any way of getting that into SHP format so we can normalize the data fields to align with the rest of our dataset?

Comment: Could you tell anything more about the RDL format?